# College project: add email verification in signup page, it can be used for login in angular 6, external apis

Tags: angular, api, angular6

This is the HTML signup page. I want when the user presses the register button, it will send an email with verification link, the api for email verification is '/verification/email' and when the user confirmd that link using a token, only then he is able to login.

If the user will not confirm that link he will not be able to login.

### signup.component.html

```
<div class="login-wrapper">
  <form #f="ngForm" (submit)="onRegister(name.value, email.value, password.value, $event)">
  <div class="form-wrapper">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="input-field">
          <input type="name" required name="name" placeholder="Full Name" name="name" id="admin-name" #name="ngModel" ngModel>
        </div>
        <div class="text-red" *ngIf="name.invalid && (name.dirty || name.touched)">
            *Name is required  
        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="input-field">
          <input type="email" required name="email" placeholder="Email Address" name="email" id="admin-email" #email="ngModel" ngModel>
        </div>
        <div class="text-red" *ngIf="email.invalid && (email.dirty || email.touched)">
            *Email is required  
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="input-field">
          <div class="input-wrapper">
            <input type="password" required name="Password" placeholder="Password" #password="ngModel" id="password-input" ngModel>
            <div class="eye-password" (click)="showPassword()"> 
              <img src="./assets/images/auth/show.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="text-red" *ngIf="password.invalid && (password.dirty || password.touched)">
            *Password is required  
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="input-field">
          <div class="input-wrapper">
            <input type="password" required name="PasswordConfirm" placeholder="Confirm-Password" #pwConfirm="ngModel" compare="Password"  id="password-input1" ngModel>
            <div class="eye-password" (click)="showPassword1()">
              <img src="./assets/images/auth/show.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="text-danger" *ngIf="pwConfirm.invalid && (pwConfirm.dirty || pwConfirm.touched)">
              <div class="text-red"> 
                <div *ngIf="pwConfirm.errors['required']">*Password Confirm is required</div>
                <div *ngIf="pwConfirm.errors['compare']">*Password Confirm do not match</div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="input-field submit-wrap">
          <button class="btn btn-pink" type="submit" id="register-btn">Register</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="input-field">
          <h4 class="text-white register-link">Already Registered</h4>
          <a [routerLink]="['/auth/login']" class="orange-link">Login Here!</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
<br>
</div>
```

### signup.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiService } from '../../services/api.service';
import { StorageService } from '../../services/storage.service';
import { Router} from "@angular/router";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-signup',
  templateUrl: './signup.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./signup.component.scss']
})
export class SignupComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private apiService: ApiService,
    private router: Router,
    private storage: StorageService) { 
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  showPassword(){
    let passwordEle = document.getElementById('password-input') as HTMLInputElement;
    let crossEyeEle = document.getElementsByClassName('eye-password')[0]  as HTMLInputElement;
    if(passwordEle.type == 'text'){
      passwordEle.type = 'password';
      crossEyeEle.style.opacity= '0.5';
    }
    else{
      passwordEle.type = 'text';
      crossEyeEle.style.opacity= '1';
    }

  }

  showPassword1(){
    let passwordEle1 = document.getElementById('password-input1') as HTMLInputElement;
    let crossEyeEle1 = document.getElementsByClassName('eye-password')[0]  as HTMLInputElement;
    if(passwordEle1.type == 'text'){
      passwordEle1.type = 'password';
      crossEyeEle1.style.opacity= '0.5';
    }
    else{
      passwordEle1.type = 'text';
      crossEyeEle1.style.opacity= '1';
    }

  }

  onRegister(name, email, password, event: Event){
    event.preventDefault();
    let loginEle = document.getElementById('register-btn') as HTMLInputElement;
    // let token = this.storage.getItem('token');
    // console.log(token);
    loginEle.innerHTML = 'Registering...'
    // this.storage.setItem('token', 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VySWQiOiI1OWFkMThlN2RlN2I5YjI1MDg2NmNkNzUiLCJyb2xlIjo2LCJjb21wYW55SWQiOiI1OWE5NDY4NjViZmJhODk5ZjE4MTBlYTkiLCJib29rbWFya0lkIjpudWxsLCJpYXQiOjE1MTQ4NjY5NjQsImV4cCI6MTY2NDg2Njk2NH0.cbeTI_AiwBWE54V2TNuzTwc7P99l9snAbiNzxDMpMe4');
   //  this.storage.setItem('userId', '59ae3b20a8473d45d11987f8')
     //  this.router.navigate(['dashboard/program-running']);

    let parameters:any = {};
    parameters.method  = 'POST';    
    parameters.url = '/signup/spoc';
    // parameters.data = {
    //   email: email,
    //   password: password,
    //   // device_os: 'web',
    //   // device_identity: 'abcdef'
    // }
    parameters.token = undefined;
    parameters.data = {
        name: name,
      email: email,
      password: password,
      device_os: 'webapp',
      device_identity: '1' 
    }
    // = "email=" + email + "&password=" + password ;

    this.apiService.sendRequest(parameters, 'account')
      .subscribe(
        (data:any) => {
          this.router.navigate(['/auth/signin']);
          loginEle.innerHTML = 'Register'
        },
        (error:any) => {
          alert(error);
          loginEle.innerHTML = 'Register'
        }
      );
  }

}
```

How can I add a verification link so that when user presses a signup button a token along with url is passed for email confirmation and when the link is confirmed, user enter email and password and from that token he can login in.

Comment: I suppose when you register you save the token in the user/account table. When a user click on the url, come to login page, and click on the login button, you can just send username, password, and token so that you can validate them on submit?

Comment: Actually i want to send an email verification link along with a token on the email provided by user. And the above is sign up.. when user clicks on register button.. an email from backend with verification link is sent on the same email id provided by user at the time of signup

Comment: When a user click the verification link it will go to the login page, right? You can send username and password as well as token to the server side(token can be obtain from the query string) when user click on the login page. On the server side you need to verify username and password are correct as well as token matches with the one you save in the database when you user register. Once token matches you can clear the token from the token field.

Comment: If you want to have 2 step verification you can send email and verification token OnInit or ngAfter... and display the message on top of login screen.

Comment: I want like this: 1. Generate a unique Token for the User and persist it
2.Send out the email message for account confirmation – which includes a confirmation link with the Token’s value. 3. When the user receives the “Confirm Registration” link on their email they should click on it.

Once they do – the controller will extract the value of the token parameter in the resulting GET request and will use it to enable the User.

Comment: I don't know how to use this in angular. I only made the html page and want to know how to add email verification in this i.e. signup page with email verification link. Signup page will only contain name, email and password and user is verified by the email confirmation. And token value should be unique for every user